# asp net mvc create visio diagram without Microsoft Office Interrop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visio

I need the abitity to create the Visio diagrams on the server side without usage of Microsoft Office. The solutions that I've found point on the using of Microsoft.Office.Interrop.Visio. Unfortunately, I cannot use Interrop by some reasons. Is there any solutions that let create visio diagrams without using Interrop on the server side ?

Comment: If you want to use Microsoft Visio, then Your code will be handling unmanaged code. as CLR does not deal with unmanaged code, You will need to use Interop services.

Comment: Though I did not test this yet and how helpful in your case, but take a look at:

[Codeplex: NetOffice - MS Office in .NET](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) [[MIT Licensed as of today](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/license)]

Comment: As in documentations, NetOffice uses COM Interop services

Comment: I have controller on the server-side and I should generate visio diagrams and send to client. The server doesn't need to have visio and office installed, the client needs. So there's no way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Aspose.Diagrams](http://www.aspose.com/.net/diagram-component.aspx) (it's not free though). As of Visio 2013 (vsdx) you could also try to generate the XML yourself. [See more here about vsdx file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228622.aspx).

But basically, there is no cheap and easy way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about the Aspose.Diagrams, unfortunately it's not free. Also I've found the solutions on the codeplex but inside they use the Interrop. The link, that you gave is good, and it looks like the only solution I can use? Besides, I can only generate vsdx files, what about the different  formats like vsd or vdw ?

Comment: VSD is binary, undocumented/proprietary, and more than 20 years old. Go figure :) VDW is also binary, focused on SharePoint and more or less deprecated as of Visio 2013. I would not recommend to dig in that direction, unless you really have to and have unlimited resources.